# Rewriting magento 1.9 core file

Tags: shipping, table-rates

I am working on a shipping module, which i have to create based on the below logic.

Shipping costs logic will be determined by unit cost and the order quantities with minimum weight as 1 lb per below setting:

- If unit price is less than $5 **and**
- Quantity ordered as below:

  - 1 to 10 -> set as 1 lb
  - 11 to 30 -> set as 2 lbs
  - 31 to 50 -> set as 3 lbs
  - Over 51 -> set as 5 lbs
- If unit price is more than $5.
- Quantity ordered as below:

  - 1 to 5 -> set as 1 lb
  - 6 to 10 -> set as 2 lbs
  - 11 to 20 -> set as 3 lbs
  - 21 to 30 -> set as 5 lbs
  - Over 31 -> set as 10 lbs

I have created a module which is going to set the package weight according to the above rules. The customer is going to use the table rate shipping method for shipping cost.

But every time the package weight is overwritten by tablerate shipping method

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. It's hardly possible to help you with problems in your custom code if you don't show any code. How is your module setting package weights? Please update the question with more details.